# Ajax and PHP problem not sending mail

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem here, I have two files form.php and index.php , my form.php has an ajax to fetch data from index.php , also my index.php has a mail function which is running perfectly when we run index.php directly, but when i form.php to fetch data from index.php this mail function is not running ..... 
can any body tell me whats the problem why ajax does not make my index.php send mail ?????

Comment: We can't help if you don't share your code.

Comment: Code? What Code? I don't see any Code!

Comment: How should we be able to fix your code if you don't share it? Guessing?

Answer (score 0):

Requesting index.php via AJAX does run the whole script, but in order to have the mail function work properly, your AJAX request must supply the script with the proper resources as if it were to be ran directly.

Answer (score 0):

A PHP script called via AJAX should still be able to send an email.

What parameters are you using through **index.php** to generate the mail? Are they GET or POST variables? Does the AJAX call include those variables?

Have you run basic debugging in the **index.php** file? Just using `file_put_contents( 'debug.txt' , 'Debug Data' , FILE_APPEND )`?